# Translate list comprehension to Prolog

Tags: haskell, prolog, list-comprehension

I have a list comprehension in Haskell that I want to translate to Prolog.

The point of the list comprehension is rotating a 4 by 4 grid:

```
rotate :: [Int] -> [Int]
rotate grid = [ grid !! (a + 4 * b) | a <- [0..3], b <- [0..3] ]
```

Now in Prolog, I translated it like this:

```
rotateGrid([T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15],
       [T0,T4,T8,T12,T1,T5,T9,T13,T2,T6,T10,T14,T3,T7,T11,T15]).
```

Can we do better?

Comment: Why do you call this a rotation? it seems more like a transposition or symmetry about an axis (it's an involution with a fixed axis).

Comment: You're actually right that it's not strictly a rotation. But it has the same effect as a rotation in the sense that columns become rows, and rows become columns. That was all that mattered for my use of this function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `findall/3` for list comprehensions (Cf. the [SWI-Prolog Documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)).  E.g.,

```
?- findall(X, between(1,10,X), Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

`Xs` is a list holding all values that can unify with `X` when `X` is a number between 1 and 10. This is roughly equivalent to the Haskell expression `let Xs = [x | x <- [1..10]]`(1). You can read a `findall/3` statement thus: "find all values of [First Argument] such that [Conditions in Second Argument] hold, and put those values in the list, [Third Argument]".

I've used `findall/3` to write a predicate `rotate_grid(+Grid, ?RotatedGrid)`. Here is a list of the approximate Haskell-Prolog equivalences I used in the predicate; each line shows the relation between the value that the Haskell expression will evaluate to and the Prolog variable with the same value:

- `a <- [0..3]` = `A` in `between(0, 3, A)`
- `b <- [0..3]` = `B` in `between(0, 3, B)`
- `(a + 4 * d)` = `X` in `X is A + 4 * D`
- `<Grid> !! <Index>` = `Element` in `nth0(Index, Grid, Element)`

Then we simply need to find all the values of `Element`:

```
rotate_grid(Grid, RotatedGrid) :-
    findall( Element,

            ( between(0,3,A),
              between(0,3,B),
              Index is A + 4 * B,
              nth0(Index, Grid, Element) ),

             RotatedGrid
           ).
```

To verify that this produces the right transformation, I down-cased the Prolog code from the question and posed the following query:

```
?- rotate_grid([t0,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14,t15],
       [t0,t4,t8,t12,t1,t5,t9,t13,t2,t6,t10,t14,t3,t7,t11,t15]).
|    true.
```

---

**Footnotes:**

(1): `between/3` isn't actually the analogue of `[m..n]`, since the latter returns a list of values from `m` to `n` where `between(M,N,X)` will instantiate X with each value between M and N (inclusive) on backtracking. To get a list of numbers in SWI-Prolog, we can use `numlist(M,N,Ns)`. So a stricter analogue for `x <- [1.10]` would be the conjunction `member(X, Ns), numlist(1, 10, Ns)`.

Comment: For caveats see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You want a permutation of a list. The concrete elements are not considered. Therefore, you can generalize your Haskell signature to

```
rotate :: [x] -> [x]
```

This is already a very valuable hint for Prolog: the list's elements will not be considered - elements will not even be compared. So a Prolog solution should be able to handle variables directly, like so:

```
?- rotateGrid(L,R).
   L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I,_J,_K,_L,_M,_N,_O,_P],
   R = [_A,_E,_I,_M,_B,_F,_J,_N,_C,_G,_K,_O,_D,_H,_L,_P].
```

And your original definition handles this perfectly.

Your version using list comprehensions suggests itself to be realized via backtracking, certain precautions have to be taken. Using `findall/3`, as suggested by @aBathologist will rename variables:

```
?- length(L,16),rotate_grid(L,R).
   L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I,_J,_K,_L,_M,_N,_O,_P],
   R = [_Q,_R,_S,_T,_U,_V,_W,_X,_Y,_Z,_A1,_B1,_C1,_D1,_E1,_F1].
```

The built-in predicate `bagof/3` addresses this problem. Note that we have to declare all local, existential variables explicitly:

```
rotate_grid2(Grid, RotatedGrid) :-
   bagof(
     Element,
     A^B^Index^    % declaration of existential variables
       (  between(0,3,A),
          between(0,3,B),
          Index is A + 4 * B,
          nth0(Index, Grid, Element)
       ),
     RotatedGrid).
```

For lists that are shorter than 16 elements, the Haskell version produces a clean error, but here we get pretty random results:

```
?- L=[1,2,3,4],rotate_grid(L,R).
   L = [1,2,3,4], R = [1,2,3,4].
?- L=[1,2,3,4,5],rotate_grid(L,R).
   L = [1,2,3,4,5], R = [1,5,2,3,4].
```

This is due to the unclear separation between the part that enumerates and "generates" a concrete element. The cleanest way is to add `length(Grid, 16)` prior to the goal `bagof/3`.

### List comprehensions in Prolog

Currently, only B-Prolog offers a form of list comprehensions:

```
R@=[E: A in 0..3,B in 0..3,[E,I],(I is A+4*B,nth0(I,L,E))].
```

However, it does not address the second problem:

```
| ?- L = [1,2,3], R@=[E: A in 0..3,B in 0..3,[E,I],(I is A+4*B,nth0(I,L,E))].
L = [1,2,3]
R = [1,2,3]
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use a loop predicate foreach/4**

If the comprehension should retain variables, which is for example important in constraint programming, a Prolog system could offer a predicate foreach/4. This predicate is the DCG buddy of foreach/2.

Here is how variables are not retained via findall/3, the
result R contains fresh variables according to the ISO
core semantics of findall/3:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.7.1)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.

?- functor(L,foo,5), findall(X, 
     (between(1,5,N), M is 6-N, arg(M,L,X)), R).
L = foo(_5140, _5142, _5144, _5146, _5148),
R = [_5210, _5204, _5198, _5192, _5186].
```

And here is how variables can be retained via foreach/4,
the resulting list has the same variables as the compound
we started with:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 3, Runtime Library 1.3.0
(c) 1985-2018, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland

?- [user].
helper(N,L) --> [X], {M is 6-N, arg(M,L,X)}.

Yes

?- functor(L,foo,5), foreach(between(1,5,N),helper(N,L),R,[]).
L = foo(_A,_G,_M,_S,_Y),
R = [_Y,_S,_M,_G,_A]
```

Using foreach/4 instead of bagof/3 might seem a little bit over the top. foreach/4 will probably only show its full potential when implementing Picat loops, since it can build up constraints, what bagof/3 cannot do.

foreach/4 is an implementation without the full materialization of all solution that are then backtracked. It shares with bagof/3 the reconstruct of variables, but still allows backtracking in the conjunction of the closures.